# Custom data object with functions in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to build a custom DataSource object as the data portion of a table component, however VueJS appears to be re-writing the object to make it reactive.  The vue component can access the direct data values fine (i.e. this.dataSource.columns or this.dataSource.sort) however I can't call any of the functions in the object, and I can't (for example) use the dataSource.rows() function to retrieve the filtered/sorted row data.  Can Vue only work with plan javascript data objects?  Or is there a trick I can use to make this work?

I'd like to use the object in a table component like:

```
<table ref="bodyTable" class="table-body">
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="row in dataSource.rows" >
            <td v-for="column in dataSource.columns">{{row[column.name]}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However vue can't seem to use the dataSource.rows function, or call any of the other methods in the object.

```
function RealtimeDataStore(columns,data,sort,filter){
    this.columns = columns;
    this._data = data;
    this.sort = sort;
    this.filter = filter;
    this.keyField = findKeyColumn();
    function updateData(data){
        //TODO: merge or insert the data into the this._data array
        //TODO: let parent component know data changed
    }
    function findKeyColumn(){
        for(var i=0;i<columns.length;i++){
            if(columns[i].isKey) return column[i].name;
        }
        return null;
    }
    function setSort(sortData){
        //TODO: verify sortData is in correct format and all columns are found
        this.sort = sortData;
        //TODO: let the component know data may have changed
    }
    function setFilter(filterData){
        //TODO: verify filterData is in correct format and all columns are found
        this.filter = filterData;
        //TODO: Let the component know data may have changed
    }
    function rows(){
        //TODO: filter data if needed
        //TODO: sort data if needed
        return this._data;   
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, yes, it's best to stick with [plain javascript objects](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) for data in Vue.

However, in this case that is not why the code doesn't work.

First, `rows` is declared inside the scope of the `RealtimeDataStore` and is not accessible outside it. Second, the code doesn't call it as a function. `row in dataSource.rows` should be `row in dataSource.rows()`.

Here is an example of how you might get the code to work.

```js
console.clear()

function DataSource(){
    this.rows = function(){
      return [1,2,3]
    }
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    source: new DataSource()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="row in source.rows()">
    {{row}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice that `rows` is exposed as a function on the object returned as a result of `new DataSource()`.

Comment: Thank you - I missed that.  Is there any way to trigger a reactive event when the rows would change?  With simple data objects, vue sets up an Observer on it - can I do the same for a function?

Comment: @JohnP Well, instead of a function, you could make it a property and then it would be automatically made reactive.